# TabPy (Tableau) how to automate producing pdfs from a workbook

Tags: python, tableau-api, tabpy

I have created a workbook with multiple pages that are populated based on a single filter. I would like to automate printing a pdf of the workbook for every value of the filter.

I understand that this can be achieved with tabcmd with tableau server, but I don't have access to it and would rather not go via the server if I can do it all on my computer.

Can I do it with TabPy, and if so how? I've found nothing applicable by googling.

Comment: TabPy is a way to call Python code from within Tableau. It's use is for extending the analytics capabilities by leveraging python code with Tableau data. It's not used to automate things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print a PDF via the URL by adding the :format parameter. You can pass filter values via the URL. Merge those two concepts and voila, you will have your PDFs for every filter value.

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/actions_fieldvalues_url.html

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed_list.html

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to reply to this, but thanks belatedly.