# Tableau Server: How to select/include specific sheets from a workbook (for exporting to PDF) *via* script / console / API?

Tags: javascript, console, tableau-api

In **Tableau Server** I'm trying to find a way to **select specific sheets** from a workbook (for **exporting to PDF**) ***via* script / browser dev console / tabcmd / URL / API**. Here's a real / live example, which can be played around with: https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_sample_export_to_pdf.htm

[image: Exporting specific sheets from Tableau Workbook to PDF]

So far I tried, *inter alia*, various JavaScript commands to get the right element and trigger a "click", but so far to no avail... the underlying *.js files reveal a lot but so far I had no luck in getting the proper handle.

(I managed to give the *impression* that the sheets were selected, i.e., the checkboxes were shown and ticked via my JavaScript, but that didn't budge the actual selection, e.g. the "2 of 6" in the screenshot above.)

---

Related links:

- https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd_cmd.htm#id7cb8d032-a4ff-43da-9990-15bdfe64bcd0
- [Export a specific sheet from Tableau using tabcmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411284/export-a-specific-sheet-from-tableau-using-tabcmd)
- [TabPy (Tableau) how to automate producing pdfs from a workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663092/tabpy-tableau-how-to-automate-producing-pdfs-from-a-workbook)
- https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00001HuPQSSA3/how-to-set-default-options-for-showexportpdfdialog-?_ga=2.20070778.390974142.1655121966-1741765833.1651754073&_gac=1.204654884.1654237999.EAIaIQobChMI9oaVytSQ-AIVtRSLCh0gNw-xEAEYASAAEgLApvD_BwE (*Q: Ideally, I would also like to pre-select certain sheets for the user as well. -- A: I don't think it is possible using the javascript api.*)
- https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_ref.htm
- https://www.tableau.com/developer/tools

Comment: https://public.tableau.com/vizql/v_202212205150833/javascripts/vqlweb.js --> `function tc(){}function Nf(a,b){switch(a){case"button":case"input":case"select":case"textarea":return!!b.autoFocus}return!1}`

Comment: `<div aria-label="Sheet Selection" aria-multiselectable="true" aria-orientation="horizontal" class="thumbnail-picker_f1qay9lg" data-tb-test-id="thumbnail-picker-list" role="listbox"><div aria-selected="true" class="thumbnail-wrapper_f1gupj42" data-itemindex="0" data-tb-test-id="sheet-thumbnail-0" role="option" tabindex="0" title="Obesity" data-eventutils-optout="true">
<div class="f1hykqr2"><div class="thumbnail-image____><div class="overlay_f1awuv37"></div><div class="checkbox-selected_fau34jg"></div></div><span class="thumbnail-title_fmb090t" aria-hidden="true">Obesity</span></div></div>`

Answer (score 0):

One approach (there might be much better ones...), which works for [here](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_sample_export_to_pdf.htm):

```
const bla = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail-wrapper_f1gupj42')
bla[1].click()
```

That toggles the checkbox on the "College" sheet above :-)

Comment: So far inexplicably, in the real "Tableau Server", which looks pretty much identical, this click (and variations of it) do nothing... so for now I can only toggle the checkbox in this dummy page...

Comment: Maybe the reason it doesn't work in the non-public Tableau is the `Content Security Policy of your site blocks the use of **eval** in JavaScript` from **vqlweb.js / script-src / report only**... ? as the public API in the link above does not feature / list that "Issue" in the console...

Answer (score 0):

A solution which worked (not only worked in the API but also in my use case) is [recording](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/recorder/) a [puppeteer](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/puppeteer/) [script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/puppeteer/get-started/) and using the keyboard only (e.g. <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, etc) to select the individual pages; recording mouse clicks did not work that well, but who needs a mouse anyway?

Comment: Keyboard "events" could also be handled in JavaScript directly and probably applied here too alternatively... e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316395/javascript-for-handling-tab-key-press